# Pynecone - programmatically filling a textarea without breaking user input

Tags: textarea, pynecone

My first steps with pynecone: I'm trying to pre-fill a textarea based on checkboxes and dropdowns, and then enable the user to edit the generated text.

However, when I hook up the events such that I can populate the textarea, whenever the user enters a character, the on_change event fires and moves the cursor to the end of the text area, making editing impossible.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is my minimal code example:

```py
from pcconfig import config

import pynecone as pc

class State(pc.State):
    q1_response: str

    q1_c0: bool = False
    q1_c1: bool = False
    q1_c2: bool = False
    
    def add_response(self, *args):
    
        text = ''
        if self.q1_c0:
            text += q.options[0][1] + '\n'
        if self.q1_c1:
            text += q.options[1][1] + '\n'
        if self.q1_c2:
            text += q.options[2][1] + '\n'

        self.q1_response = text.strip()


class Question:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = 'This is the question'
        self.options = [
            ('None', 'Nothing'),
            ('Answer 1', 'The long answer 1.'),
            ('Answer 2', 'The long answer 2.'),
        ]

q = Question()


def index():
    return pc.container(
        pc.text(q.q, font_size="1.5em"),
        pc.vstack(

            pc.checkbox(q.options[0][0] + ' - ' + q.options[0][1], on_change=State.set_q1_c0),
            pc.checkbox(q.options[1][0] + ' - ' + q.options[1][1], on_change=State.set_q1_c1),
            pc.checkbox(q.options[2][0] + ' - ' + q.options[2][1], on_change=State.set_q1_c2),

            pc.button("Add", on_click=State.add_response, bg="blue", color="white"),

            pc.text_area(
                value = State.q1_response,
                placeholder = 'The long answer will go here',
                on_change = State.set_q1_response,
                rows = 8,
            ),
        ),
    )   


app = pc.App(state=State)
app.add_page(index)
app.compile()
```

I tried a variety of events, but the only way I can get pynecone to update the textbox (see the example), editing of the textarea by the user is impacted.

I did find a recent issue that seems to be related to my observations ... so it could be an open bug github.com/pynecone-io/pynecone/issues/900

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of the pynecone, it is a bug.
https://github.com/pynecone-io/pynecone/issues/1087
So there is no solution for it right now.
But we can continue to observe and wait its updates.